# getdate.y grammar doubts

Tags: c, timezone, bison, freebsd, getdate

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/~checkout~/src/usr.bin/tar/Attic/getdate.y?rev=1.9.12.1;content-type=text%2Fplain;hideattic=0

I am trying to understand how `yyTimezone` is calculated in code below:

```
| bare_time  '+' tUNUMBER {
    /* "7:14+0700" */
    yyDSTmode = DSToff;
    yyTimezone = - ($3 % 100 + ($3 / 100) * 60);
}
| bare_time '-' tUNUMBER {
    /* "19:14:12-0530" */
    yyDSTmode = DSToff;
    yyTimezone = + ($3 % 100 + ($3 / 100) * 60);
}
```

How I understand is, lets say the timestamp is `2011-01-02T10:15:20-04:00`; this means its `0400` hours behind `UTC`. So to convert it into `UTC`, you add `0400` hours to it and it becomes `2011-01-02T14:15:20`. Is my understanding correct?

How is that achieved in the codeblock I pasted above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input would encode the offset like `-0400`. The `0400` part of that would be returned as the `tUNUMBER` token (presumably holding an unsigned value). This token is matched by the grammar rules, and can be used as `$3`.

To get the actual offset in minutes from the value `400`, you first have to split it up in two halves. The hours part can be obtained with `$3 / 100` (ie. `4`), and the minutes part with `$3 % 100` (ie. `0`). Since there are 60 minutes in an hour, you multiply the hours by 60, and add the minutes to that (`$3 % 100 + ($3 / 100) * 60`), which would give the value `240`. Then all that's left, is to add the sign, and store it in `yyTimezone`.

After all that, `yyTimezone` will contain the timezone offset in minutes.

Comment: x % 100 and x / 100 - this pattern should have lite the bulb :D; anyways, thanks for your response.